# How to calculate struct padding in c++11 during compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

**PROBLEM**

I have a std::vector of a gazillion Foo's

```
struct Foo
{
  int   m_i;
  char  m_c;
  char  m_padding[3];   // want to replace this
};
```

I can fwrite this chunk of contiguous Foo's quickly in binary form all in one shot.

My problem is, if I don't put in that m_padding explicitly, calculate it, and clear it myself, valgrind will complain about uninitialized writes.

**QUESTION**

*Is it possible to write a template class in C++11 which will calculate that padding for me during compile time?*

If so, I could just add it at the end of all my Foo's and auto-initialize/clear them without complaint from valgrind.

I can do it manually by calculating sizeof( padding ) = sizeof( Foo ) - sum( sizeof( parts )), but it would be nice to create some kind of class for this calculation since all information is available at compile-time.

For simplicity, assume that Foo has trivial layout (type_traits is an important, but tangent issue).  Also, ignore ordering issues/cross-platform issues.

**Possible Approach**

This doesn't answer my original question directly, but hvd's suggestion implies a simpler approach that seems to work for some simple test cases that I tried:

```
template<typename T>
struct BZero
{
  BZero() { std::memset( this, 0, sizeof( T )); }
};

struct Foo : public BZero<Foo>
{
  int   m_i;
  char  m_c;
};
```

Comment: You *could* just use `memset` to clear the entire structure before filling the other fields. In general, your structures may have padding between members too, which valgrind would (or at least should) complain about equally, and adding a padding member at the end would not fix that problem.

Comment: @hvd I like your suggestion - I could create a class template which takes as a parameter Foo and memset in that constructor.  That way, Foo can still initialize in the normal way.  I will try this out and update the OP if it works out ok.  Thx.

Comment: Note: if you derive from a base class, the compiler is allowed to stash the derived class members in the base class padding.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Out of curiosity: Do you know of any compiler that actually performs this optimization?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've added a simple approach to the OP that seems to work, but I just realized that if, for some freakish reason, the compiler decides to pad in-front of Foo, this will not point to the beginning of Foo.  Could this happen?  Are there other problems with this approach?

Comment: @pmr `struct S1 { int a; char b; ~S1() {} }; struct S2 : S1 { char c; }; int main() { return sizeof(S2) - sizeof(S1); }` returns 0 on my system (x64 Linux, both in 32-bit mode and in 64-bit mode). But for reasons unknown to me, it doesn't happen on my system if the destructor is removed.

Comment: @kfmfe04: you are guaranteed no padding will occur prior to the first member in your usecase, see **§9.2 [class.mem]**, *19/ A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its
initial member [...]*; I advise you, therefore, to make sure `Foo` remains a *standard-layout* struct.

Comment: @kfmfe04 I withdraw my previous comment. It used to be the case that your constructor would render the use of `memset` invalid even if `this` points to the start of the full object, but the current standard does seem to allow the part I worried about.

Comment: @MatthieuM. ty for that reference.  So if I do a static_assert on std::is_standard_layout<T>::value && std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value (for my block fwrite), I should be set?  I will update the OP appropriately.

Comment: @kfmfe04: I believe it would, but don't take my word for it. You would still have to ensure that no pointer is in there too.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can see two ways:

1. Use a `union` of your class and an array of `char` as big as the class
2. Use a templated class and meta-programming to figure out all the paddings

Needless to say the former seems much easier, so here you go:

```
template <typename T>
class ZeroedClass {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    ZeroedClass(Args&&... args) {
        new (&_.t) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // Need other special members as well

    ~ZeroedClass() { _.t.~T(); }

    // Accessors
    T& access() { return _.t; }
    T const& get() const { return _.t; }

private:
    union U {
        U() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(T)); }

        char buffer[sizeof(T)];
        T t;
    } _;
}; // class ZeroedClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood well, what about this :

```
struct FooBase {
    int i;
    char c;
};

template<typename T, size_t total>
struct padded : public T {
    char pad[total-sizeof(T)];
};

typedef padded<FooBase, 8> Foo;
```